# returning related field in template

Tags: django

I have the following classes, I can get the related objects through this `{{plantpart.fraction_id.fraction}}` going up the models, but I want to go the other way. I know I need a related_name to avoid the `_set` ending and it needs to be in a nested for loop.

So how do I correct the following:

```
{% for f in fractions %}
  {% for pp in plantparts%}
    {{pp.plantparts.fraction}}
  {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %} 


class Fraction(models.Model):
    fraction_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    composition_id = models.ForeignKey(Composition, db_column='composition_id', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    fraction = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices = FRACTIONS)

class PlantPart(models.Model):
    plantpart_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fraction_id = models.ForeignKey(Fraction, db_column='fraction_id', on_delete = models.PROTECT, related_name='plantparts')
    taxon_id = models.ForeignKey(Taxon, db_column='taxon_id', on_delete = models.PROTECT, related_name='plant_taxon', blank=True, null=True)
    part = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
```

p.s. I know I don't need to use an id, but this connects to an existing database.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Why do you want to avoid `_set` specifically? Why are  you looping through `plantparts` inside the `fractions` loop but then not using `f`? Where, specifically, are you having trouble?

Comment: I gave a minimalist example, I could have added `f.fraction` in the first loop. Avoiding _set is just good practice and I want to learn how to use related_name. I want to return all the plantparts and the related fraction, this will cause duplication of the results, but that's what I want. I can't get my head around this one.

Comment: I still don't understand. You know how to get to the fraction from the plantpart, it's just like you said: `pp.fraction_id.fraction`. No related_name required. (And no, it definitely is *not* best practice to avoid _set, if it was then it wouldn't be the default.)